# Ленты новостей RSS

Tags: rss

Здравствуйте, я уже писала, насчет rss (выдавалась ошибка). Оказывается, код правильный, и если в базе обычный текст - все отлично выводится, а если много символов, выдается ошибка, например: `-` (выделено) или тег `<p>` почему-то выделяется как ошибка. Как мне это исправить, ведь у меня в текстах много символов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов косить весь HTML. ибо он не важен особо.

Второй обрабатывать все открытые и закрытые теги + спец символы

Comment: Слешем чтоли? У меня что-то не получается.

Comment: Убирать html? можно стандартными ф-ями php

Comment: Спасибо,попробую!